# Why "ls" doesn't show the file that "find" discovered?

Tags: find, ls

In Ubuntu, when I am up in "/" folder I type:

```
sudo find . -name  .erlang.cookie
```

and the result is:

```
./var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```

Then, when I am on the folder `/var/lib/rabbitmq` and I type `ls`, I see one file named mnesia.

When I type the `find` command again, I see

```
./.erlang.cookie
```

-- what does that mean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Unix, a filename beginning with a dot, like `.erlang.cookie`, is considered a [hidden file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) and is not shown by bare `ls`. Type `ls -a` to also show hidden files.

From [`man ls`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

```
   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .
```

However, you can show a hidden file with `ls` if you specify the name:

```
$ ls .erlang.cookie
.erlang.cookie
```

Comment: Or `ls -A` if you don't want to show `.` and `..`. Having them displayed is generally only useful if you use `ls -l`.

Answer (score 6):

In Unix, hidden files start with dot(.), so when you issue "ls" command it will not list them out.
If you want to print hidden file with long listing format you can use following command,

```
$ls -la

where,
l - use a long listing format
a- do not ignore entries starting with .
```